# Handle location updates in the background

Tags: windows-phone-7, service, backgroundworker

I'm new in developing application for Windows Phones.
Till now I'm only experienced in developing desktop applications in .NET and mobile apps for Android platform.

I want to develop an application which consumes the location updates of the GeoCoordinateWatcher in the background (user starts position tracking and switch over to any other apps on the phone). And as soon as a certain criteria matches for the current location I'll inform the user about that event. (turn on vibration module or play a specific ring tone, ...).

The only two things I've read in the internet is using MPN (push notifications) or Agents (e.g. PeriodicAgent). But both of them aren't suitable.

I need some basic hints how to achieve the behavior mentioned above. Aren't there any background tasks?

Thank you very much!
Kind regards, Danny

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, periodic agents are only thing you can use. But they are run automatically every 20-30 mins and its not suitable if you need to check the location more often.